# Magento 2 : Call Function From app/code to app/design

Tags: magento2, phtml, helper

Is there any way to call function defined in the `app/code/Custom/Module/helpers/HelperClass.php` inside the `app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_Theme/template/html/View.phtml` in Magento 2?

I'm fairly new with magento 2, so I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: does you get answer from my code or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the helper function into phtml file, you can use this code.

```
<?php
$helper = $this->helper('Custom\Module\Helper\HelperClass');?>
$helper->Yourfunction();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not call helper directly in phtml.

You should provide helper instance dependency to the block that will renders the phtml and create a function in your block class that calls the helper and call that function in the phtml.

You should define it like below:

```
protected $helperData;


public function __construct(
     ....
    \{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Helper\Data $helperData,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
    ....
}


public function doSomething()
{
    return $this->helperData->doSomething();
}
```

add below code in your phtml for calling helper:

```
$block->doSomething();
```

Comment: But block is located in the /app/code right? What if I want to call this $block->doSomething() inside the phtml of my custom theme which is located in /app/design?

Comment: Create an extension which should be use for your theme